# Nustar DNS doesn't send NS record for sub zones. Is this correct behavior?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

I have these domains:

```
  company.com
a.company.com
b.company.com
c.company.com
```

Sub domains "a" and "b" are under the same zone of `company.com` in the GUI (albeit with an extra dot in the hostname field).  The zone `c.company.com` is separate from the zone that hosts `a` and `b`.

When I delegated a secondary/slave to "company.com" I don't see any NS record or any records for `c.company.com`.

**Questions**

- Should a secondary of `company.com` zone (that has `a` and `b`) include NS records for `c`?  (I can't resolve anything under `c`
- What is the expected value of the NS for `c.company.com` in this case before and after delegation?
- Is this expected behavior for DNS in general? (for secondaries to not have NS records for some subdomains)
- What are my options to make `c` resolve or redirect at the secondary?

I was able to get `c.company.com` to resolve at the NS for `company.com` if I created a stub zone (a Windows 2003 feature) for `c.company.com`.  I had to do this for each stand alone secondary.

My intent is to get a better understanding of the problem, that is platform agnostic, and prevent this from happening again in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If c.example.com. is a delegated zone then there should be NS records for it in example.com., as well as A records if the nameserver is in-baliwick. For example, in example.com.:

```
c.example.com.      IN  NS  ns.c.example.com.
ns.c.example.com.   IN  A   192.0.2.10
```

These records should be returned by both primary and secondary servers for example.com. Before delegating the zone there would be no NS records for it.

I don't know how to achieve this on Windows Server ;-)

Comment: What does in-baliwick mean?

Comment: @makerofthings7 That the hostname of the nameserver is within the domain which it is serving. This means that the parent zone needs to return an A record for the nameserver, otherwise the resolver can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

`example.com` should have an entry for `c` that includes the 2 or more NS records.  It also needs to know the address(es) of any nameservers within the `c.example.com` subdomain.   Querying a nameserver for `example.com` should return the nameservers.  Running `nslookup` in command mode with the following command should give you an idea what is happening.

```
nslookup
norecursive
c.example.com ns1.example.com
c.example.com ns.c.example.com
```

`dig` if available is the tool of choice.  A command like `dig @ns.example.com c.example.com` should return data required to locate the nameservers.  This will include `NS` records, `A`, and optionally `AAAA` records.